# Extended errno in LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

Following are the lines of my code in C:

```
ldap_bind_s(ld, root_dn, root_pw, auth_method) != LDAP_SUCCESS  

ldap_perror( ld, "ldap_bind" );//to print the EXACT error like 525,52e
```

When executed

```
Project  ./a.out CN=username,OU=ABC,DC=example,DC=com wrong-pasword
     ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
   additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment:  
AcceptSecurityContext      error, data 52e, vece
```

Here the string 52e after data represents the extended error.
Can anyone please suggest how do I access this extended error directly. Currently I am parsing the string to extract this value. Normally when I print LDAP_OPT_ERROR_NUMBER it returns just 49(INVALID_CREDENTIALS) but that is not sufficient for me. How do I get the code(only code) of extended error.
I even tried printing ld->ld_errno but it is not allowing me since no memory has been alloted to ld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse error string in order to extract error number,as you are unable to to see the error code from LDAP structure,because it is `opaque datatype` and you can access element of `LDAP structure` only through `routines` which can see the incomplete definition of structure.